# Store a cookies from zombie.js into tough-cookie?

Tags: node.js, cookies, zombie.js

How would you take cookies returned by zombie.js into a tough-cookie jar? I know this:

```
browser.cookies
```

returns all the cookies that zombie has in JSON format. I think that would mess up tough-cookie. Any thoughts on this?